# código linguagem C imprimir pares de um à cinquenta

Tags: c, printf

Exercício de programação em C:
Enunciado: "Escreva um programa que imprima todos os pares entre 2 e 50. Para saber se o número é par, basta você ver se o resto da divisão por 2 é igual a 0."

o que eu fiz:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
for(int n = 2; n <= 50; n++){
    int rest = n % 2;
    if(rest == 0){
        printf("%d", n);
       }
}
}
```

O que imprimiu:
2468101214161820222426283032343638404244464850

Comment: Detalhe que vc pode fazer o `for` pulando de 2 em 2: `for(int n = 2; n <= 50; n += 2)` - aí nem precisa testar o resto da divisão, porque todos os números com certeza serão pares (a menos, é claro, que o exercício exija que se faça de um em um e use o operador `%`)

Comment: Muito obrigado mesmo!
A sua resposta e ajudou em um outro exercício!!!

Answer (score 1):

Sua lógica está correta, e o resultado também, acontece que você não deu espaços ou fez uma quebra de linha entre os resultados, com isso todos os números pares foram impressos um ao lado do outro.

---

Você pode editar o seu `printf` para dar um espaço:

```
printf("%d ", n);
```

Ou uma quebra de linha:

```
printf("%d\n", n);
```

Até mesmo uma tabulação horizontal:

```
printf("%d\t", n);
```

---

Seu código final vai ficar mais ou menos da seguinte forma:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    for(int n = 2; n <= 50; n++){
        int rest = n % 2;

        if(rest == 0) {
            printf("%d\n", n);
        }
    }
}
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/@Dadinel/ColorfulMinorSequel

Comment: Cara, Muito Obrigado Mano!!!!

Comment: Imagina, se já tinha feito tudo! :D